# Select an element by its index without jquery

Tags: javascript

I have nothing but only this useless code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic_area').index(input+4);
```

What is my mistake?

Important:

- Don't use jQuery,
- `input` is a variable

Comment: Show us your HTML. And what is the issue? getElementsByClassName is not supported in older browsers

Comment: what do you mean "select"? what do you mean "index"?

Comment: select means that i want to select the element to perform actions on it and index means ,when use `eq()` in jQuery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a regular array index:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic_area')[input + 4];
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eYmXE/

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use a method, change `.index` to `.item`...

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic_area').item(input+4);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FfMJz/